# Is there any event available to call after plugin is installed?

Tags: plugin

I have to make some **alter** in **database** after **plugin** is **installed**. Is there any events that is called after plugin is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make an install script for your plugin.

> An optional script file (PHP code that is run before, during and/or
>   after installation, uninstallation and upgrading) can be defined using
>   a  element. This file should contain a class named
>   "IntallerScript" where  is the name of
>   your extension (e.g. com_componentname, mod_modulename, etc.). Plugins
>   requires to state the group (e.g. plgsystempluginname).

See more info about it in the Script file section of [Manifest files](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) doc.